# Why isn't the try and catch working?

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm trying to make a program that tells the person if they can ride a roller coaster or not. It works as long as the input is valid, but I want it to show a message saying to retry if the user inputs something else. I tried using try and catch, but it still shows an error (NumberFormat Exception). Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
private void btnCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String strHeight, strBackTrouble, strHeartTrouble;
    int intHeight;

    strHeight = txtInputHeight.getText();
    strBackTrouble = txtInputBackTrouble.getText();
    strHeartTrouble = txtInputHeartTrouble.getText();

    intHeight = Integer.parseInt(strHeight);

    try {
        if (intHeight < 188 || intHeight > 122) {
            if (strBackTrouble.equals("N") || strBackTrouble.equals("n") || strHeartTrouble.equals("N") || strHeartTrouble.equals("n")) {
                    txtOutput.setText("It is OK for you to ride this roller coaster. Have fun!");
            }
        } else  if (strBackTrouble.equals("Y") || strBackTrouble.equals("y") || strHeartTrouble.equals("Y") || strHeartTrouble.equals("y")) {
                txtOutput.setText("Sorry, it is not safe for you to ride this rollercoaster");
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        txtOutput.setText("You entered invalid input, please try again");
    }

}
```

Comment: move the try{ line to before strHeight = txtInputHeight.getText();

Comment: Try using your debugger next time. Had you just stepped through your code it would have been abundantly obvious that your try block does not encompass the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: Yeah that worked.. thank you guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
intHeight = Integer.parseInt(strHeight);
```

throws the Exception which is not in the catch block.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    intHeight = Integer.parseInt(strHeight);
    if (intHeight < 188 || intHeight > 122) {
        if (strBackTrouble.equals("N") || strBackTrouble.equals("n") || strHeartTrouble.equals("N") || strHeartTrouble.equals("n")) {
                txtOutput.setText("It is OK for you to ride this roller coaster. Have fun!");
        }
    } else  if (strBackTrouble.equals("Y") || strBackTrouble.equals("y") || strHeartTrouble.equals("Y") || strHeartTrouble.equals("y")) {
            txtOutput.setText("Sorry, it is not safe for you to ride this rollercoaster");
        }

} 
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    txtOutput.setText("You entered invalid number, please try again");
}
catch( Exception e) {
    txtOutput.setText("You entered invalid input, please try again");
}
```

java 7:

```
try {
    intHeight = Integer.parseInt(strHeight);
    if (intHeight < 188 || intHeight > 122) {
        if (strBackTrouble.equals("N") || strBackTrouble.equals("n") || strHeartTrouble.equals("N") || strHeartTrouble.equals("n")) {
                txtOutput.setText("It is OK for you to ride this roller coaster. Have fun!");
        }
    } else  if (strBackTrouble.equals("Y") || strBackTrouble.equals("y") || strHeartTrouble.equals("Y") || strHeartTrouble.equals("y")) {
            txtOutput.setText("Sorry, it is not safe for you to ride this rollercoaster");
        }

} catch (NumberFormatException e | Exception e) {
    txtOutput.setText("You entered invalid input, please try again");
}
```